# Application Insights Query to display Total Request vs Total Passed vs Total Failed

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Can any one share Azure Application Insights Query to display Total Request vs Total Passed vs Total Failed for a given test duration:
Operation  Totalcount TotalPassed TotalFailed
Request1      10          5          5
Request2      10          7          3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @  [lubumbax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7425361/lubumbax) your answer helped a lot to improve my query knowledge.

Here I am using a query to fetch the Total count, Success, and Failure response from Application insights.

[image]

The Query follows:

```
let TOTAL = requests | where timestamp > ago(1d) | summarize TotalRequests=sum(itemCount) | extend Foo=1;
let Req_TOTAL = materialize(TOTAL);

let FAILED = requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| where resultCode hasprefix "5"
| summarize Failed=sum(itemCount)
| extend Foo=1;
let Req_FAILED = materialize(FAILED);

let SUCCESS = requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| where resultCode hasprefix "2"
| summarize Success=sum(itemCount)
| extend Foo=1;
let Req_SUCCESSED = materialize(SUCCESS);

Req_FAILED
| join kind=inner Req_TOTAL on Foo
| join kind=inner Req_SUCCESSED on Foo
| extend PercentFailed = round(todouble(Failed * 100) / TotalRequests, 2)
| extend PercentSuccess = round(todouble(Success * 100)/ TotalRequests, 2)
| project TotalRequests, Failed, Success, PercentFailed, PercentSuccess; availabilityResults
```

The Result :
[image]

Comment: Hi Delliganeshs, Thanks for the usefull. i am actually looking for total, passed, failed count by operation/request. example  Request1 - 10, 2,8, Request2 - 10, 2,8. appreciate if you can help on this.